# VB Accessing dynamically created textboxes

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB form that dynamically creates 4 Comboboxes called 1, 2,3 and 4, at run time. The problem being that when it comes to access them, I read the best way is to do the following, but of course that doesnt work at all, any ideas?

Thanks,
Sam.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    x = 4
    y = 0
    Dim MyLocationX As Integer = 25
    Dim MyLocationY As Integer = 25
    Do While y <> x
        Dim DropDownlist As New ComboBox
        DropDownlist.Name = x
        DropDownlist.Location = New Point(MyLocationX, MyLocationY)
        Me.Controls.Add(DropDownlist)
        y = y + 1
        MyLocationY = MyLocationY + 30
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim z as Integer = 0
    Do While z <> x
    Dim z As New ComboBox
    MsgBox(z.SelectedValue)
    z++
    Loop



End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

A little more robust than my first suggestion:

```
 Public Class Form1
    Private _comboBoxes(3) As ComboBox

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim MyLocationX As Integer = 25
        Dim MyLocationY As Integer = 25

        For i As Integer = 1 To 4
            Dim DropDownlist As New ComboBox()

            DropDownlist.Name = i.ToString()
            DropDownlist.Location = New Point(MyLocationX, MyLocationY)

            _comboBoxes(i - 1) = DropDownlist

            Me.Controls.Add(DropDownlist)

            MyLocationY = MyLocationY + 30
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For i As Integer = 1 To 4
            MessageBox.Show(_comboBoxes(i - 1).SelectedValue)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I would recommend creating a list of comboboxes over this method. Then no type casting is needed plus you'll know which combobox your are actually handling by using a for loop.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Will have a play around with this and see how i can fit it all in, my only concern is that at runtime, there could be any number of drop down boxes, would this still work ?

Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, I think a list can handle atleast 65000 items. Just do a new list(of checkboxes) where you do Controls.add(dropdownlist) also do list.add(dropdownlist)

Comment: Your current solution uses an array. Don't use an array if you want it to scale freely. Use Dim listCmb as New List(of Combobox) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it differently, with AddHandler. Because that way you can avoid to have a button to collect the values. Just have a list with all the values and if something changed change the value in the list.
I f you still want the button I added at the end of my code

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
x = 4
y = 0
Dim MyLocationX As Integer = 25
Dim MyLocationY As Integer = 25
Do While y <> x
    Dim DropDownlist As New ComboBox
    DropDownlist.Name = x
    DropDownlist.Location = New Point(MyLocationX, MyLocationY)
    '------
    AddHandler DropDownlist.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf controlValueChanged
    '-------
    Me.Controls.Add(DropDownlist)
    y = y + 1
    MyLocationY = MyLocationY + 30
Loop
End Sub


  Private Sub controlValueChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
   'This event is fired when you change the selection in one of your comboboxes
   Dim cbo As combobox= sender 'Sender is the combobox that you change its selection
   'Do whatever you like with cbo

  End Sub
```

Don't forget to clear the custom events (Unmanaged memory)

```
   Private Sub removeControlValueChangedEvents()
    'Call that Sub when your form is closed
       For each cbo as combobox in Me.Controls
          RemoveHandler DirectCast(cbo , ComboBOx).SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf controlValueChanged
       Next

   End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For each cbo as combobox in Me.Controls
        MessageBox.Show(cbo.SelectedValue)
    Next
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Controls.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find.aspx) Method to locate your ComboBox's in the Forms ControlCollection

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim maxDropDowns, y As Integer
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        maxDropDowns = 4
        y = 0
        Dim MyLocationX As Integer = 25
        Dim MyLocationY As Integer = 25
        Do While y < maxDropDowns
            Dim DropDownlist As New ComboBox
            DropDownlist.Name = (y + 1).ToString
            DropDownlist.Location = New Point(MyLocationX, MyLocationY)
            Me.Controls.Add(DropDownlist)
            y = y + 1
            MyLocationY = MyLocationY + 30
        Loop

    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim cntrls() As Control
        For z = 1 To maxDropDowns
            cntrls = Controls.Find(z.ToString, True)
            If cntrls.Count > 0 Then
                MsgBox(CType(cntrls(0), ComboBox).SelectedValue)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

Or you can use a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx#Y0), You have many different options it all depends on what you want to do, my preference is to create a control Array assign common event handlers and pull the control that intitiated the event from the sender object.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim maxDropDowns, y As Integer
    Dim myControls As Dictionary(Of Integer, ComboBox) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, ComboBox)
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        maxDropDowns = 25
        y = 0
        Dim MyLocationX As Integer = 25
        Dim MyLocationY As Integer = 25
        Do While y < maxDropDowns
            Dim DropDownlist As New ComboBox
            DropDownlist.Name = (y + 1).ToString
            DropDownlist.Location = New Point(MyLocationX, MyLocationY)
            myControls.Add(y, DropDownlist)
            Me.Controls.Add(DropDownlist)
            MyLocationY = MyLocationY + 30
            y = y + 1
        Loop
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For z = 0 To maxDropDowns - 1
            MsgBox(myControls(z).SelectedValue)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```